# I would like to create a batch files that checks if a subfolder exists, it it does not create it

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch file to see if the folder, "Templates" exists in the folder, "C:\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates" It should go through each user name in the, "C:\users" folder. If "Templates" folder does not exist, it should create it. I have command below, but it does not create this folder in all C:\users.

```
    FOR /d %%G IN (*.*) DO (IF NOT EXIST TEMPLATES\ (md templates C:\users\%%G\appdata\roaming\microsoft\))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users"
for /d %%a in (*) do (
if not exist "%%a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates" md "%%a\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
)
```

and verify if you have administrator privileges also...

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
for /d %%g in ("C:\users\*") do (
    md "%%~g\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates" >nul 2>&1
)
```

Comment: "if there is no `template` for the current user, then create it for all users" - probably not, what's wanted.

Comment: @Stephan Oh. I guess I misunderstood his code. I'll fix. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

`md /?`: you have two arguments, so you create two directories. One (`templates`)  in your working directory and another one in the user's folder.

You don't need to check, if the folder exists, `md` will just create an error message, if it does, which you can easily redirect to nirvana:

```
FOR /d %%G IN ("C:\USERS\*") DO (mkdir "%%G\appdata\roaming\microsoft\template" 2>nul)
```

Comment: You do not need "C:\users" before %%G since the variable %%G already includes that data.